# How to understand this type of SQLException

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, insert

My app crashes with next exception without any explanation:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method:0)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1607)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1505)
```

How to fix it?

I found reason, that's because onUpgrade not called from SQLiteOpenHelper, I'm forget to change DATABASE_VERSION in new release

Comment: Paste your schema and contract classes. Have to tried to debug an see at what statement does the code throw this exception?

Comment: That's trace stack from Google Developer Console, for Galaxy Tab4 10.0 (matisse3g) device. On all other devices there is no such error, this is the first time.

Comment: Show us your code. It should be something with your `insert` query.

Comment: I *may* suppose you're running an async task when the database was yet to be created or missing some tables...

Comment: getWritableDatabase is called before insert

Comment: now error repeated on three devices yet

Comment: I found reason, that's because onUpgrade not called from SQLiteOpenHelper